# How do I know if a lambda@edge function is associated with my Cloudfront distribution?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Given a Cloudfront Distribution I created, How do I check associated lambda@edge functions?
From what I understand the empty "Functions" Section in Cloudfront console is only for 'Cloudfront functions'.

I deployed the Distribution with cloudformation containing a section in `Properties`=>`DistributionConfig`=>`DefaultCacheBehavior`

```yaml
LambdaFunctionAssociations:
  - EventType: 'viewer-request'
    LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref ViewerRequestFunctionVersion
  - EventType: 'origin-response'
    LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref OriginResponseFunctionVersion
```

The lambdas were successfully created and I can see them in aws console.

### More Background:

I followed [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/resizing-images-with-amazon-cloudfront-lambdaedge-aws-cdn-blog/) to create a cloudformation distribution with correspondingly associated lambda@edge viewer-request and origin-response functions.
Since the tutorial is a bit outdated, I had to use a newer node runtime and change a few things,
but I finally got the cloudformation stack to deploy.

Now requests that just request an image without parameter as is work fine.
As soon as I use the url parameter to resize - i.e. `d=100x100`, cloudfront gives me a 502 error.

I don't see logs in cloudwatch and I dont know how to debug the lambdas, so for starterst I would simply like to verify that the lambdas are even associated properly (and executed?).

Answer (score 4):

To see and monitor all the Lambda@Edge functions associated with your distribution, you can use the monitoring in the CloudFront console of your distribution.

Go to the monitoring section under telemetry, there you will find the CloudFront Functions and Lambda@Edge Functions separately to monitor.

Each function is a part of a specific cache behaviour. You can find the function for a specific event(origin req/viewer req etc) under the behaviours tab for that cache behaviour.

Comment: Oh I havent checked that out - in the meantime I found that I in the cloudfront-console distribution I can select and edit the default behaviour and at the bottom I can see the lambda associations. I will check your suggestion next week when I'm back at work.